# Нет перевода для кнопок в настройках профиля

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

1. Кнопка сохранения профиля.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Кнопка удаления профиля.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил переводы:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14801
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14798